# Moving array elements to the left

Tags: java, arrays

Writing a code that shifts array elements left by an int n (keyboard input) and replaces space with zeros.

Ex. `int[] data = { -1, 1, 3, 7, 5}` and I want to see `{ 3, 7, 5, 0, 0}`.
Suppose I have:

```
public static void shiftLeft( int[] data, int n )
{
    System.arraycopy( data, 1, data, 0, data.length - 1 );
    data[data.length - 1] = 0;
}
```

Any quick help would be great.

Comment: You are not using `n`. You've hard-coded `1` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but your `srcPos` argument should be `n` and the `length` argument should be `data.length - n`. You can then use the overloaded `Arrays#fill` method that accepts a start/end index to fill the rest of the array with `0`:

```
public static void shiftLeft(int[] data, int n) {
    System.arraycopy(data, n, data, 0, data.length - n);
    Arrays.fill(data, data.length - n, data.length, 0);
}
```

Testing this with your example input yields the following:

```
int[] data = { -1, 1, 3, 7, 5};
shiftLeft(data, 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

Output:

```
[3, 7, 5, 0, 0]
```